Importing a module created from string in Node.js using URL.createObjectURL
I want to evaluate string as a module and get this module's exports. I used to do it before in browser environment, but now somewhy I cannot use the same method in node.js
What I tried:
const virtualUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['export default 123'], { type: 'text/javascript' }));

import(virtualUrl).then(module => {
    console.log(module.default);
});

This code works as it supposed to in browser, but node says something like
Error: Cannot find module 'blob:nodedata:35b64fea-47a3-4b77-934d-9a07213bac8e'

Why does this happen, where is my url? And how can I get my string module imported?

Uh, nodejs import does not accept arbitrary urls? You can use a data: url though.

You can export with eval:
    const moduleCode = "export default 123";
    
    const evaluatedModule = eval(`(() => { ${moduleCode} })()`);
    
    console.log(evaluatedModule.default); // Output: 123

